# Get Number in Separated String of Numbers

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript string which consists of two numbers separated by a `/`.

I want to be able to separately be able to get each of the numbers.

When there are only 1 digit integers, I can get the values pretty easily, but I don't know what to do when there are two digits integers.

Single Digits:

```
var string = "5/9";
var firstVal = string.slice(0, 1);
var secondVal = string.slice(-1);
```

Multiple Digits Variations:

```
var string = "10/23";
var string = "9/21";
var string = "45/2";
```

Comment: `let [a, b] = '10/23'.split('/')`?

Comment: just use the `split('/')` function on each string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to break your problem into steps.

### Breaking the string into two parts

```js
console.log("bob/marie".split("/"));
//  ["bob", "marie"]
```

### Casting the strings to numbers

Let's assume that you are sure that they are valid numbers.
There are many different ways to cast numbers in Javascript. My favourite is this multiply by 1.

```js
console.log("132445.85" * 1);
// 132445.85 as number
```

### Combine the two operations

```js
console.log( "6532.11/4535.77".split("/").map( v => 1 * v ) );
```

The map above applies the function in all elements.

### Finally let's put this in data in some HTML result, just for fun

```js
function showNumbers(element) {
  // read the input value as string
  let text = element.value;
  // convert the string into an array breaking by "/"
  let numbers = text.split("/").map( v => v * 1 );
  // get the div element that we are going to put the list
  let myDiv = document.getElementById("my-div");
  // create a list
  let ul = document.createElement("ul");
  // creating a total column
  let total = 0;
  numbers.forEach(
    function(n) {
      // create a list item
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      // set the number as the list item value
      li.innerHTML = n;
      // add the list item into the list
      ul.appendChild(li);
      // we can add the numbers
      total += n;
    }
  )
  // create a list item
  let liTotal = document.createElement("li");
  // set the number as the list item value
  liTotal.innerHTML = "Total " + total;
  // add the list item into the list
  ul.appendChild(liTotal);
  // remove all elements from my div
  myDiv.innerHTML = "";
  // make the new list the element into the div
  myDiv.appendChild(ul);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" style="width:200px" onKeyUp="showNumbers(this)"/>
<div id="my-div">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const num = "23/2/3"
const result = num.split("/")

console.log(result);
```

You can easily achieve that using `string.split`. This is known as string delimiter

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split` like this:

```js
var string = "10/23";

console.log(string.split("/"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match digits despite the operator and omit unwanted parts.

```js
const
    string = ' 123/ 4 ',
    values = string.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);

console.log(values);
```